# FingerPrinter Setup

Tags: vb.net

I am Developing Attendance System for FingerPrinter
When I need to Connect the Device It Displays

> unable to connect the device error code=-6.

Now I want to know what is meant by error code -6?

Comment: the Link Below is not allowed more than 10 users

Comment: my Question is totally different from the link below.

Comment: Search like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=FingerPrinter+vb.net+error

Comment: What is the exact name of the device? Does it have a website, with documentation? Where exactly is the error generated? where is your code for connecting it? You haven't given us any contextual information which we need in order to help you. We can't guess what device you're using or what code you're trying to run. Don't forget we cannot read your screen, your disk...or your mind :-). Please update your question with more info. Thanks.